# protege compound class restrictions with some and only

Tags: owl, protege, restriction, object-property

I've looked around and cannot really find an answer to why the following property restriction works in one case but does not work in the other. I am trying to combine "some" and "only" object property restrictions to require that a defined class have only a certain property+object *and* that it also have at least one such property+object defined. I cannot get this combination to produce the intended class inference. I want to use it to identify an instance with a certain combination of type and property assertions as the specified class. I do not intend to use it to assign an instance to be a type of that class (if that matters).

The RDF/OWL file is at: https://pastebin.com/NZMCuZjE
I built it using Protege 5.5. Both reasoners (FaCT++ 1.6.5 and HermiT 1.4.3.456) give the same result.

I expected that defining **X_LetterThing** as equivalent to
  **LetterThing** *and* (**hasLetter** *only* **X**) *and* (**hasLetter** *some* **X**)
would have the effect of inferring that instance **x_letter_thing_test** is of Type **X_LetterThing** since **x_letter_thing_test** has asserted type **LetterThing** and has object property assertion **hasLetter x**, but there is no such inference.

A second related problem is that the instance **compound_letter_thing_test** is not inferred to be of type **Compound_LetterThing** unless I include a covering axiom for class **LetterThing**, which I really can't have. (Also, adding the covering axiom has no effect on the first problem.)

Is this OWA or something else?

Thanks!

```
d.c
```

Comment: Open world assumption is the problem here. For the second in addition also the absence of a unique names assumption, which affects min cardinality. Making all individuals different from each other would solve this

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for your response, but that did not seem to have any affect. I made at first all the instances of Letter different individuals, then I made *all* the individuals different and neither made any change to the inferencing. Do you have any suggestions on what I could read to understand the more gnarly aspects of OWA?

Comment: Also - I don't really understand why making the subclasses of **Letter** - ie, **A**, **X**, **Y** - all disjoint doesn't achieve the same ends in this case as making **a**, **x1**, and **y** different individuals.

Comment: I never said that making all individuals different from each other will solve the issue. But it is necessary to make your min cardinality restriction working. Otherwise, having an individual `x` connected via property `p` to `y` and `z` doesn't mean that `x´ fullfills the restriction `p min 2` because there is no unique names assumption which means we can't assume that `y` and `z` are not the same indiviudual

Comment: regarding your other stuff, it's the Open World Assumption. that's another thing. also, I do not know what you always mean with *"covering axiom"* - this a non-standard term, or at least I never heard of it.